# Why does the <body> element sometimes get a border/margin even with no specification to do so?

Tags: html, css, border, document-body

To further visualize this:

- There is no margin or border specification for body in the CSS file.
- In the developer tools, the  element's content covers this unwanted area.
- Every individual/child element in body stays within the expected area. (No child element extends into the unwanted margin/border)

Comment: Code examples? Pictures of the issue? Tools/Plugins used?

Comment: I will supply that in just a moment.

Comment: `<body>` always has an `8px` `margin` by default.

Comment: I must've not saw it in my code because it must a browser default stylesheet.